# Visual Studio - indentation for .config files

Tags: visual-studio, formatting, indentation, auto-indent

Default formatting is set to 4 spaces, but the config uses 2 by default (e.g. `Web.config` / `packages.config`, `App.config`, etc.).

I've tried changing various settings in Text Editor for XML files / Basic / Plain text but indentation stays at 4 spaces ... instead of desired 2. Which language settings should I change?

Note: I'm using VS 2022, but I suppose this should be similar for VS 2019 / 2017.

Comment: do you use `tab`s or is this about automatic formatting? have you tried changing the `tab` behavior to `Insert spaces` and changed `Indent size`? check this [options-text-editor-all-languages-tabs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/options-text-editor-all-languages-tabs?view=vs-2022).

Comment: I use spaces and I did try - I'm just not sure which language I should change. It actually work swith `editorconfig` but I would like to get an IDE solution so I don't have to put `editorconfig` in every single repo.

Comment: last month I uninstalled all VS to manage disk space, so I can only speculate to help. since the `.config` file type might be associated with another content type, maybe `XML`, you may try either editing that category, putting this file extension into the `JSON` category, or maybe setting file content type on the fly. I use VS Code, and this is easy as clicking on the file type button on the right side of the status bar. check for a file extension sign on the UI first.

Comment: hmm, forget about the `JSON` :) guess your config files need be `XML`, then maybe file type association is broken somehow.